# How to fix FloodWaitError when adding a user to a Telegram group inPython?

Tags: python, try-catch, telegram, telethon

I dont know what's wrong, but I'm stuck on making my program. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Telegram Marketing\add members in channel\add members.py", line 50, in <module>
    user_to_add = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 404, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 516, in _get_entity_from_string
    result = await self(
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 47, in __call__
    raise errors.FloodWaitError(request=r, capture=diff)
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 71180 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)
Unexpected Error *
```

My code:

```
channel = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel_username))
mode = 1
for user in users:
    try:
        print ("Adding {}".format(user['id']))
        if mode == 1:
            if user['username'] == "":
                continue
            user_to_add = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])

        else:
            sys.exit("Invalid Mode Selected. Please Try Again.")
        client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel,[user_to_add]))
        print("Waiting 60 Seconds...")
        time.sleep(60)
    except PeerFloodError:
        print("Getting Flood Error from telegram. Script is stopping now. Please try again after some time.")
        time.sleep(900)
    except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
        print("The user's privacy settings do not allow you to do this. Skipping.")
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("Unexpected Error")
        continue
```

Comment: Please remember that adding users without their consent is considered spam, and will likely get both your account and the channel limited, maybe even deleted.

Comment: yes is a remarkably spam i was just experimenting and also many clients wants this i dont know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel_username,[user['username']]))
```

GetFullChannelRequest returns ChatFull and using it as input of InviteToChannelRequest will rise type error. Anything **entity-like** will work.

- Channel invite link
- Channel username
- Channel user id

can be used as channel argument of InviteToChannelRequest.
also,

- username,
- user id,
- phone number

will work for users argument.

Comment: Just tried your solution, but unfortunately the error is still there :(
Used channel username and user id...